# How to run electrical wire in concrete under the tile

Tags: electrical, foundation, structural, slab

I'm running 6 feet of electrical wire from the wall to kitchen island and going to do it this way:

1. make a trench around 1 inch in depth
2. put 1/2 inch flexible conduit there
3. cover conduit with about 1/2 inch of concrete
4. apply liquid membrane (preparation for tile)
5. lay tile over it.

Is this solution is reliable? I know that trench perfectly should be deeper but I wouldn't like to cut my slab too deep and my guess is that if I lay large format tile over it then I should be good. Thoughts?

Comment: I think they sell/rent concrete groove cutters but if I was doing it with a carbide blade, I **might** cut a V groove to get the concrete out easily.   And practice on some scrap wood first to get the angles and spacing correct.

Comment: I have no problems cutting the ranch deeper - I'm just concerned about breaking its integrity b/c of soil shifts in my area. So I thought that 1 inch deep won't harm it.

Comment: I meant "cutting the slab deeper"

Comment: How thick is the slab?

Comment: How can I find out? I've read it's 4-6 inches for residential houses.

Answer (score 2):

FMC "flex" isn't allowed in concrete. In 362.10 ENT (smurf) is allowed to be embedded in concrete, so I think it would OK, but the inspector could have issue with meaning of "embedded" with such shallow cover, which could be  up to interpretation of "similar finish" by AHJ.

> NEC 300.4(F) Cables   and Raceways Installed in   Shallow Grooves.
> Cable or  raceway-type    wiring  methods installed   in  a   groove, to  be  covered by  wallboard,  siding, paneling,   carpeting,  or  similar
> finish,   shall   be  protected   by  1.6 mm  (1∕16   in.)    thick   steel   plate,  sleeve, or  equivalent  or  by  not
> less  than    32-mm   (11∕4-in.)  free    space   for the full    length  of  the groove  in  which   the cable   or  raceway
> is    installed.
>
> Exception No. 1:
> Steel plates, sleeves,    or  the equivalent  shall   not be  required    to  protect rigid
> metal conduit,    intermediate    metal   conduit, rigid  nonmetallic conduit,
> or    electrical  metallic tubing.
>
> Exception No. 2: A    listed  and marked  steel
> plate less    than    1.6 mm  (1∕16   in.)    thick   that    provides
> equal or  better  protection  against nail    or  screw   penetration shall   be  permitted.

Comment: Can I just use 1/2 PVC pipe then?

Comment: I think I would use sch80, so it would be Listed for use where subject to physical damage (NEC 362.12(c)).

Comment: Makes sense. And you think it's gonna be OK if I cover it with only 1/2 inch of concrete and then thinset+tile?

Comment: I think with sch80 you'll be fine. Most places you can call the inspectors and ask for their interpretation.

Comment: @Rainmaker -- make sure you're using PVC *conduit*, *not* DWV pipe!

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine. I'm not sure the depth requirements apply to interior wiring encased in conduit and concrete.

You might, however, find PVC to be cheaper than flexible conduit.

Comment: isn't a slab considered to be "an outside"?

Comment: @Rainmaker The catch here is that I read the NEC rules about depth to apply to open ground. You absolutely do not want electrical cable (conduit or not) 1" underground inside a flower bed, under your yard, etc. But nobody is going to be sticking a shovel into your kitchen concrete, and conduit with THHN wires are sufficient for a "wet" zone.